# Leaflet error: clearLayers is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I'm using a Leaflet offline map with React where I manually load in a `countries.js` GeoJSON file with every country in the world. I then conditionally color each country depending on data received from `this.props.data`, which works initially.

However, the issue comes from updating the colors when new `this.props.data` is coming in.

I have tried managing it in these two components:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.data) {
        let map = this.map;
        console.log(map); // It shows the leaflet object!
        console.log(nextProps.data); // It's logged
        console.log(this.props.data); // Also logged
        if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
            map.clearLayers(); // Error comes here?
            console.log("New data doesn't match old!"); // This logs correctly
        }
    }
},

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.props.data){
        let map = this.map;
        if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
            L.geoJson(this.countries, { // from import
            }).addTo(map);
         }
    }
},
```

What am I doing wrong? The condition is met, if the old data doesn't match the new, the map should clear all layers with `clearLayers();`. I could understand this error if the map couldn't be found; but I am accessing it with `this.map`, so it doesn't appear to be a scoping issue.

Comment: r u sure `clearLayers()` function exist ? check the spelling may be it could be a spelling mistake.

Comment: `clearLayers` is method of the [LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-clearlayers) not of the map

Comment: Seems like you're right, I have to objectify the geojson data and run clearLayers it with `this` to avoid scoping constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`clearLayers()` is [a method of `L.LayerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-clearlayers), **not** a method of [`L.Map`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map).

Store the instance of `L.GeoJson` that you create when running `L.geoJson(...)`, and implement more fine-grained control of when it's added/removed from the map.

Comment: You are correct! I solved it by storing the L.GeoJSON in an object and then calling it both in `componentDidMount` and thereafter in `componentWillReceiveProps` where I could call `.clearLayers()` on it. Thanks.